# Resolving symbols in shared object to executable

Tags: linux, dynamic-linking

How can I make an executable that loads a shared object *dynamically* and resolve its undefined symbols to the executable itself? On Linux.

For example, the shared object has

```
extern int a;
void f() { a=1; }
```

and the executable has

```
int a;
```

I'd like to call `f()` from the executable and have the value of `a` changed.

Thanks.

Comment: That should work out of the box.. how did you try to compile your example?

Comment: @Phillip Not really... shared object (so.c) using `cc so.c -o a.so -shared -fPIC` and executable (loader.c) `cc loader.c -o loader -ldl`. Run with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PWD ./loader`. `loader` complains about 'undefined symbol: a'. Shared object loaded with `dlopen("a.so", RTLD_NOW)`.

Comment: Ah, I overlooked the *dynamically* in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `dlopen` man page:

> External  references  in  the  library are resolved using the libraries in that library's dependency list and any other libraries previously opened with the RTLD_GLOBAL flag.  If the executable was linked with the flag "-rdynamic" (or, synonymously, "--export-dynamic"), then the global symbols in the executable will also be used to resolve references in a dynamically loaded library.

So recompiling your main application with `-rdynamic` should help.